# cn1PostMessage is undefined on Android. PostMessage is not working

Tags: codenameone

I created a webview (BrowserComponent) and added a listener:

```
BComp.addWebEventListener(BrowserComponent.onMessage, e->{
  Display.getInstance().callSerially(()->{
    Dialog.show("Message", (String)e.getSource(), "OK", null);
  });
});
```

Then, in the JavaScript of the embedded website, I called `cn1PostMessage` and `postMesage`. This works well in the simulator! But when building the application, on Android, it does nothing (`cn1PostMessage` is undefined and `postMessage` is not received by the main program).

```
var msg = "test";

if(window.cn1PostMessage) {
    window.cn1PostMessage(msg);
} else {
    window.parent.postMessage(msg, '*');
    // Tried: window.postMessage(msg, '*');
    // Tried: window.top.postMessage(msg, '*');
}
```

What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you do this after "onLoad" was invoked in the JS side?

Comment: @ShaiAlmong Thank you. No, but used a TimeOut of 7 seconds and created an action on button press. `cn1PostMessage` is undefined. But it works well on the Simulator. I think this happens only on Android. In the past I used ReactNative and their webview and I got the same problem on Android. I solved that creating a function like: `send = function(message) { window.ReactNativePostMessage(message);} ` and then use that function. Tried here too, but without success.

Comment: The post message listener is installed in the onStart event. Can you check if `onStart()` is invoked for the page: `b.addWebEventListener(BrowserComponent.onStart, e -> {...});` If it isn't invoked there might be an issue with the surrounding web page that's causing an error

Comment: @ShaiAlmog tried. `onStart` event is invoked. But `window.cn1PostMessage` is undefined on the webpage. The webpage is a blank html document with the script: `window.onload = function(){ window.cn1PostMessage("test"); }`. I think there is a problem with Android's webview.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I also tried to register a custom callback using `addJSCallback`. It works on the simulator but not on Android.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried building the [BrowserComponentPostMessageSample](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Samples/samples/BrowserComponentPostMessageSample/BrowserComponentPostMessageSample.java), and it seemed to work fine on my Galaxy S8, Android 8.

If you're finding that `window.cn1PostMessage` is undefined, then either there was a javascript error in page load that prevented that callback from being installed, or your code is running before the CodenameOne initialization code has run.

I have just added support for the "android.webContentsDebuggingEnabled" display property, which will make the app's web views debuggable using [Chrome's remote development tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews).  This will make it easier for your to track down such issues.  See [usage example](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Samples/samples/BrowserComponentPostMessageSample/BrowserComponentPostMessageSample.java#L52):

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("android.webContentsDebuggingEnabled", "true");
```

This will be available in Friday's update (Dec. 6/19).

In the mean time, I recommend starting with the [BrowserComponentPostMessageSample](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Samples/samples/BrowserComponentPostMessageSample/BrowserComponentPostMessageSample.java) and modifying it to suit your needs from there.

Alternatively, if you can post a test case to demonstrate the issue, I can look at it.

Comment: Thank you! I just tried the `BrowserComponentPostMessageSample`. It can send messages to the website using `postMessage` but no message is received by the program when pressing `Send` from inside the webpage (the dialog does not appear). Using an Android 6.0.1 phone.

Comment: That's strange.  I just tried that example on an Android 6.0 device, and it worked fine.  What device are you testing on?  Are there any errors reported in your android device log?  If not, you may need to wait until the update on Friday to debug the javascript and see what the error is.

Comment: This is a Finlux 5000 Dual, Android 6.0.1, Kernel 3.10.49.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it is really strange as I can't see any errors. Will try on other Android device too.